# How to call external api after publishing an event about the success update in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, masstransit

I have an update consumer where I am updating my details in a database. Upon successfull update in the database:

```cs
if (dbUpdated)
{
    await _UpdatedPublisher.GetResponse<UpdatePublisherResponse>(new UpdatedEventMessage
    {
        RegistNumber = request.RegistrationID
    });
}
```

Here I am publishing an event to inform about the `DBUpdateStatus`. My requirement now is to send an email to the registered user after the successful completion of the database update.

The email id and the salutation name (eg `<fname> <LName>`) I need to capture from an external system. That is based on the `RegistNumber` I will get the id from my existing database and that id need to pass
to the external endpoint (API). Based on the email address and `fname` and `Lname` getting from the external system, I need to send an email alert.

I am using Azure service bus with Masstransit. I am stuck after publishing an event - how do I call my current database and then based on the data retrieved how to call external system and how do I send an email?

Can someone help me the next step in masstransit application after publishing the event which I mentioned above.

A sample example to proceed on the implementation

Comment: This is probably easier to do with a Powershell script than inside a c# application.  Here is a c# app : https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/transports/azure-functions and https://dgtechboost.com/2020/07/20/azure-service-bus-topic-with-masstransit/  Here is similar PS : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156805/azure-powershell-cmdlet-for-creating-azure-service-bus-queue-and-topics

Comment: @jdweng unfortunately i cant use powershell, i neeed to strict to masstransit and asp.net core

Comment: Powershell is written using the Net/Core library so running in powershell is the same as c#.  Your are making an HTTP Request/Response to from server the connection looks the same from any client.